# Can we use intransitive verbs with passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I asked a question about *passive voice* [“The attack happened” or “The attack was happened”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120487/the-attack-happened-or-the-attack-was-happened)

And the answer was:

> We only use the passive for *transitive verbs*, ones with an object ... but it doesn't work for *intransitive verbs* like happen ...

But, I noticed some people use *passive voice* with *intransitive verbs*.

> - Police said the man **was gone** by the time cops arrived and officers didn’t find him nearby. [The Suffolk Times](https://suffolktimes.timesreview.com/2017/02/73609/blotter-calverton-man-charged-with-dwi-in-peconic/)
> - Later on, Polanski was sincerely made his apologies in public against Samantha and saying that he regretted what **was happened** before. [The classical arts](http://www.theclassicalarts.com/articles/42689/20170224/roman-polanski-was-seen-in-a-press-conference-rape-victim-says-its-over-now.htm)
> - The company's stock **was fell** as much as 14% on Thursday. [Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.com/tremor-video-ceo-resigns-on-q4-earnings-2017-2)

Unless I the above are not a *passive voice* and I misunderstand it. When can we use *intransitive verbs* with *passive voice*?

Comment: **gone** is not passive/transitive but an adjective.  **was happened** is an error; it should be **had happened**.  **was fell** is an error; it should be **had fallen** or simply **fell**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we don't make a passive verb from an intransitive verb

---

> . . . the man was **gone** . . .

[Gone](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gone) here functions as an adjective, not a past participle.

---

> . . . what was happened . . .

Unfortunately, this is a grammatical error. As explained by Stangdon in the recent post, a passive sentence cannot be formed using an intransitive verb.

---

> . . . was fell . . .

This is a two-in-one error. This *verb to be* is used to mark a progressive aspect and passive voice, which both require a participle form of verb. Another problem is that the author tries to make a passive construction using an intransitive verb.